# python selenium login error

Tags: python, selenium

so am trying to login in my Instagram acc using selenium in python and i keep getting this error , this is the code am using:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def login():
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get('https://instagram.com/accounts/login')             
    emailElement = browser.find_element_by_id("lfFieldInputUsername")
    emailElement.send_keys("username")
    passElement = browser.find_element_by_id("lfFieldInputPassword")
    passElement.send_keys("password")
    time.sleep(3)
    passElement.submit()
    browser.close()
    time.sleep(2)

def main():
    login()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Which error ?!?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than passElement.submit() find the Log In button and click on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can either find the login button and perform a click() action or you can use this, import Keys and send Keys.ENTER after password this will basically press enter button after you enter password

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
passElement.send_keys("password"+Keys.ENTER)
```